# Can I add more sections to state in state diagram?

Tags: plantuml

Each state in the state diagram has 2 sections, the top one is state name and bottom has all the state attributes. For example, for the following:

```
@startuml
Bob:aaa
Bob:bbb
Bob -> Alice
@enduml
```

The diagram has "aaa" and "bbb" in the bottom section.

Is it possible I can add more sections to a state? Or some divider lines? Basically I want to separate "aaa" and "bbb" in the above example more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hints about Class bodies at https://plantuml.com/class-diagram#08ca680401eefe3a, you can try the following separators:

```
@startuml
Bob:aaaaaaaaaaaa
Bob:....
Bob:bbb
Bob:ccccc
Bob:====
Bob:dddd
Bob:----
Bob:eeeeeeee\n====\nfffff
Bob -> Alice
@enduml
```

[image]